# I'm trying to build a 16-bit adder in Verilog but my output and carryout always have a value of X

Tags: verilog, output, quartus, modelsim

```
module Eric_Project_1 (a, b, o, co);
    input [15:0] a;
    input [15:0] b;
    wire ci;
    output [15:0] o;
    output co;
    wire[15:0] z;
    wire cz;
    assign z = 16'd0;
    assign cz = 1'd0;
        
    full_adder_16Bit b1 (.a(a[15:0]), .b(b[15:0]), .ci(ci), .o(z[15:0]), .co(cz));
    assign o = z;
    assign co = cz;

endmodule 



///////////
// ADDER //
///////////

module full_adder_16Bit(a,b, ci, o, co);
    input [15:0] a;
    input [15:0] b;
    input ci;
    output [15:0] o;
    output co;
    wire c1;
    wire c2; 
    wire c3;
    wire wc;
    
    full_adder_4Bit d1 (.a(a[3:0]), .b(b[3:0]), .ci(ci), .o(o[3:0]), .co(c1));
    full_adder_4Bit d2 (.a(a[7:4]), .b(b[7:4]), .ci(c1), .o(o[7:4]), .co(c2));
    full_adder_4Bit d3 (.a(a[11:8]), .b(b[11:8]), .ci(c2), .o(o[11:8]), .co(c3));
    full_adder_4Bit d4 (.a(a[15:12]), .b(b[15:12]), .ci(c3), .o(o[15:12]), .co(co));

endmodule 

module full_adder_4Bit(a,b, ci, o, co);
    input [3:0] a;
    input [3:0] b;
    input ci;
    output [3:0] o;
    output co;
    wire c1;
    wire c2;
    wire c3;
    
    full_adder e1 (.a(a[0]), .b(b[0]), .ci(ci), .o(o[0]), .co(c1));
    full_adder e2 (.a(a[1]), .b(b[1]), .ci(c1), .o(o[1]), .co(c2));
    full_adder e3 (.a(a[2]), .b(b[2]), .ci(c2), .o(o[2]), .co(c3));
    full_adder e4 (.a(a[3]), .b(b[3]), .ci(c3), .o(o[3]), .co(co));
    
endmodule 

module full_adder(a,b, ci, o, co);
    input a;
    input b;
    input ci;
    output o;
    output co;
    wire sum1;
    wire c1;
    wire c2;
    wire wc;
    
    half_adder f1 (.a(a), .b(b), .o(sum1), .co(c1));
    half_adder f2 (.a(sum1), .b(ci), .o(o), .co(c2));
    assign wc = c1 + c2;
    assign co = wc;
    
endmodule 

module half_adder(a,b, o, co);
    input a;
    input b;
    output o;
    output co;
    wire w;
    wire wc;
    
    assign w = a ^ b;
    assign wc = a * b;
    assign o = w;
    assign co = wc;
    
endmodule 


module Eric_project_1_tb();

reg[15:0] a;
reg[15:0] b;
reg ci;
wire[15:0] o;
wire co;
reg z;
reg cz;

Eric_Project_1 a1 (.a(a), .b(b), .o(o), .co(co));

initial begin
    a = 16'd0;
    b = 16'd0;
    ci = 1'd0;
    z = 16'd0;
    cz = 1'd0;

#45 
    a = 16'd65535;
    b = 16'd1;
#45 
    a = 16'd1;
    b = 16'd1;
#45 
    a = 16'd2;
    b = 16'd2;
#45 
    a = 16'd3;
    b = 16'd3;
#45 
    a = 16'd4;
    b = 16'd4;
end
endmodule
```

[image]

Comment: Been a while since I used verilog. But I always let the synthesis tool do the work. If I want to imply an adder I just say o = a + b + ci or something like that. Why are you trying to manage it down to the bit level almost?

Comment: @mkeith thank you for the suggestion, I tried creating a 17 bit wire 'f', I set f = a +b. I then set the output equal to the first 16 bits of 'f' and the carryout equal to the 17th bit of 'f'. However that still gave me some 'X's in my output. Is there a different way  I should approach this?

Comment: @mkeith sorry, I realized the issue with the f wire was that I was initializing it. Your method works fine now. Thank you

Comment: RiceBoy25, if you solved your problem, it would be good for you to write up a quick answer with the code that worked. It is perfectly OK to write your own answer and even to accept your own answer (after some system enforced delay time). I feel like my comment is too short to be a real answer. But if you post some code that could be a complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `X` on your outputs because there are problems in the `Eric_Project_1` module.

You have multiple drivers for the `z` and `cz` nets, which results in contention.  Since they are connected to outputs of the `full_adder_16Bit` module, you should not make continuous assignments to them as well.  You should delete these lines:

```
assign z = 16'd0;
assign cz = 1'd0;
```

Also, the `ci` wire is undriven, which means it defaults to the value `Z`.  This value is propagated as `X` when it is used elsewhere in the code.  One way to fix this is to drive it to 0, although you likely meant to have this as an input port and drive it from the testbench.

Here is a new version of the code which eliminates the `X`'s:

```
module Eric_Project_1 (a, b, o, co);
    input [15:0] a;
    input [15:0] b;
    wire ci = 0;
    output [15:0] o;
    output co;
    wire[15:0] z;
    wire cz;
        
    full_adder_16Bit b1 (.a(a[15:0]), .b(b[15:0]), .ci(ci), .o(z[15:0]), .co(cz));
    assign o = z;
    assign co = cz;

endmodule
```

---

<sup>Note: I realize that the OP has found a workaround for the problem, as seen in the Comments on the Question.  I figured I'd write up this answer in case the reason for X's in the original Question was not clear.</sup>

Comment: thank you very much, this modification worked for me, and thank you for explaining what I did incorrectly.

Comment: @toolic yeah the goal is not just to help the OP, but to also write an answer which will help other people in the future when they find this question using a search engine. Thank you for writing a real answer.